# Successive pointer allocations; Reallocated or allocated distinct?

Tags: c, memory

If I allocate memory to pointers in a loop successively, does the compiler consider it as a single instance? Concretely:

```
for (i = 0; i < SOME_VAL; i++)
{
  char *p = NULL;

  p = malloc(sizeof(char));

  SEND_POINTER_ON_NETWORK(p);
}
```

Will the compiler at every execution create a new instance of `p` or will it continue allocating memory to `p`? I am using VS2010.

Answer (score 1):

```
char *p = NULL;
p = malloc(sizeof(char));
```

Each call to malloc() within the loop allocates new memory location to the pointer `p` , if you are trying to extend the already allocated memory to `p` then use `realloc()`.

Answer (score 0):

The memory management system looks for a free memory slot at the size of the argument in malloc (in this case sizeof(char)). You do not free the memory from one iteration to the next. Therefore, the memory management system 'sees' the memory as occupied and allocates a new memory slot to pointer p.
You have a memory leak in your code.

Answer (score 0):

From ISO/IEC 9899:

(known as c99 standard)

> 7.20.3.3 The `malloc` function
>
> Synopsis
>
> 1 `#include <stdlib.h>`
>
> `void *malloc(size_t size);`
>
> Description
>
> 2 The malloc function allocates space for an object whose size is specified by `size` and
>   whose value is indeterminate.
>
> Returns
>
> 3 The malloc function returns either a null pointer or a pointer to the allocated space.

The behaving you expect would be made by realloc, which is described as follows:

> 7.20.3.4 The `realloc` function
>
> Synopsis
>
> 1 `#include <stdlib.h>`
>
> `void *realloc(void *ptr, size_t size);`
>
> Description
>
> 2 The realloc function deallocates the old object pointed to by `ptr` and returns a
>   pointer to a new object that has the size specified by `size`. The contents of the new
>   object shall be the same as that of the old object prior to deallocation, up to the lesser of
>   the new and old sizes. Any bytes in the new object beyond the size of the old object have
>   indeterminate values.
>
> 3 If `ptr` is a null pointer, the `realloc` function behaves like the `malloc` function for the
>   specified size. Otherwise, if `ptr` does not match a pointer earlier returned by the
>   calloc, malloc, or realloc function, or if the space has been deallocated by a call
>   to the `free` or `realloc` function, the behavior is undefined. If memory for the new
>   object cannot be allocated, the old object is not deallocated and its value is unchanged.
>
> Returns
>
> 4 The `realloc` function returns a pointer to the new object (which may have the same
>   value as a pointer to the old object), or a null pointer if the new object could not be
>   allocated.

Also notable is the fact, that MSVC compiler isn't strict conform to the standard in all topics.

But in the both cited cases I know they are conform with it. So it is also valid for your question.